# Copy and reordering in array

Tags: php

I have for example:

```
$array = array(
   array('aaa', 'bbb'), 
   array('ccc', 'ddd'), 
   array('eee', 'fff')
);
```

What is the best way to get such an array:

```
$array = array(
   array('aaa', 'bbb'), 
   array('bbb', 'aaa'), 
   array('ccc', 'ddd'), 
   array('ddd', 'ccc'), 
   array('eee', 'fff'), 
   array('fff', 'eee')
);
```

?

After all first array in `$array` I would like copy this array and reordering.

Is other way than foreach and create new array? Maybe `array_map`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: assuming we're have an array of arrays:
`$result = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item){$carry[]=$item; $carry[]=array_reverse($item);return $carry;},array());`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one using array_merge, but with creating new array

```
<?php
$array = array(
   array('aaa', 'bbb'), 
   array('ccc', 'ddd'), 
   array('eee', 'fff')
);
$array2 = $array;
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    $a=$array[$i][0];
    $b=$array[$i][1];
    $temp = $a;
    $a = $b;
    $b = $temp;
    $array2=array_merge($array2, array(array($a,$b)));
}
print_r($array2);
echo json_encode($array2);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => aaa [1] => bbb ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>
>   ccc [1] => ddd ) [2] => Array ( [0] => eee [1] => fff ) [3] => Array (
>   [0] => bbb [1] => aaa ) [4] => Array ( [0] => ddd [1] => ccc ) [5] =>
>   Array ( [0] => fff [1] => eee ) )

**JSON OUTPUT**

```
[
  [
    "aaa",
    "bbb"
  ],
  [
    "ccc",
    "ddd"
  ],
  [
    "eee",
    "fff"
  ],
  [
    "bbb",
    "aaa"
  ],
  [
    "ddd",
    "ccc"
  ],
  [
    "fff",
    "eee"
  ]
]
```